# How to build Prism4.5 for WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, build-process

I am trying to build Prism in .net 4.5. There's a conflict with assembly versions of Unity 3.0 and Unity Extensions.

I have Disassembled a WPF (Prism).dll file (Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.dll) using ILDASM, there I got 3 files with extensions like .IL, .res and .g.resources. I have changed the version number of a referenced file in metadata of the .IL file and assembled the file into .dll.

After using the new (Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.dll)  with updated (3.0.0.0 instead of 3.0.1208.0)  version number of referenced Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Unity.dll, I am getting below exception.

> **Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)**

I have signed the new dll but with an untrusted certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this as we updated to using .NET 4.5 with Unity 3 and Prism. You need to re-sign UnityExtensions in order to use Unity 3.0.XXX.X

Here is a few easy steps that will get you through:

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/443219

Comment: Where will I find the key file I need for signing?

Comment: Erm.. you will most probalby NOT find it. That's the WHOLE point of signing! Authors of Prism will not give you their keys, or else you, me, Frank or Barbara would be able to add malicious code to Prism and publish it on the Internet claiming that this is the "good version of Prism" that everyone should use. And everyone would see that this bad version is signed by Prism's authors. Wrong way!

Comment: It will work if you create your own public/private key pair, have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f05ezxy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's why when you change the assemblies, you must sign them with your own keys. From now on, they are marked as built-by-You and everyone knows that they are changed and that You are responsible and that You are guaranteeing that they are OK - not Prism's authors :)

Comment: Uh.. user2951819 - I'm sorry if I misunderstood.. but I get that question so many times.

Comment: I agree with @quetzalcoatl, they are now signed by you

Comment: @emedbo I solved the problem described above but couldn't build prism 4.5. Getting some other errors. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @embedo Which version or Service locator did you use 1.0.0.0 or 1.1.0.0? And how did you solve the problem of referencing Unity 3.0.0.0 instead of unity 2.1.505.0?

Comment: @user2951819 I dont think you need to rebuild Prism for using it with .NET 4.5. In my similar quest I didnt for sure. Just downloaded latest version from Codeplex then resigned ServiceLocator as described above.

Comment: @emedbo Why didn't you redirect Unity Extensions to use unity 3.0.0.0 instead of resigning it?

Comment: @emedbo Which version of service locator did you use 1.0.0.0 or 1.1.0.0?

Comment: Im sorry but I really dont remember which version.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with assembly verification. Because you edited it, you need to re-sign it. Because you could have added evil code to the already-verified DLL. [Check out this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243141%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for disabling verification, but I don't think that is a long term solution.

Comment: I have signed the new dll but with an untrusted certificate.

Comment: @user2951819: Still, your signature will not match the signatures that are remembered in all other assemblies all over the world. They were compiled with that-original-hash of Prism. If you edited Prism's assembly and re-signed it, you'd need to now re-build all other assemblies that you use in your project that were build using the old-signed-original-Prism to make them remember the new signature now. Or, disable the verification.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl If I disable verification, I will have to disable it for all referenced assemblies. Is there any way to disable verification for all referenced assemblies? SN -Vr <assembly name> disables verification of only the specified assembly and throws "disable all referenced assemblies" compiler error.

Comment: Sorry, I blindly quoted the "disable" suggestion from William. I didn't actually really though about it. I'd rather suggest against it. Recompiling the second DLL with new re-signed Prism reference will  surely be easier and **much safer** thing to do. Really. Btw, just see **emedbo**'s answer